# New Chrome Update TLD Issue

Tags: laravel-valet

Just updated Chrome and now all my local development domains (example.dev) aren't working.

I changed it to .test using `valet domain test` but Chrome just treats that as a search for "example.test" when I type it in to the address bar.

I know I can disable search from the address bar, but I'd rather not. Has anybody found a fix for this?

Comment: Type `http://example.test` ?

Comment: That worked, but I never had to do that before